# YII dropdown menu, 2 models

Tags: php, yii

I am new in PHP and yii framework so I need some help with the dropdown menu. In my database I have 2 tables - Category - id, name and News - id, title, content, category_id. How could I make the relation between these two controllers? When I post news I must choose the category from drop down menu. I'm sorry for the stupid question but I can't do it at this moment.

Comment: Please post some code ie news creating controller and view so that the people here can help you

Comment: More importantly, post the model - sounds like you should be a defining a relationship in the model, so that everything is treated as one big object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place this in your News model:

```
    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
        );
    }
```

and this in your Category model:

```
    /**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'newsItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'News', 'category_id'),
    );
}
```

whenever you have an instance of your Category, you can refer to your multiple news items like so:

```
$category = Category::model()->findByPk(1);

$category->newsItems; //an array of News objects
```

and you can refer back to the category like so:

```
$news = News::model()->findByPk(1);

$category = $news->category; //a Category object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your asking about how to show all the categories for selection when your **creating** a news item. In your form for creating the news object you need something like:

```
$cats = Category::model()->findAll();
$cats = CHtml::listData($cats, 'id', 'name');
$form->dropDownList($model, 'category', $cats);
```

For the relation between them and accessing it afterwards see Benjamin Bytheway's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do what paystey wrote all in one line like this:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'Category', CHtml::listData($CategoryModel::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'Text ASC')), 'CategoryID', 'Text'), array('empty'=> ' -- Select A Category -- '));?>
```

The last parameter of the list data is just what should display when the page loads.